# UI5 - switch off letterbox for a single view

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to switch on/off letterboxing for a single view? I have an app with the letterboxing switched off in manifest.json (`fullWidth` property of `sap.ui`). Now I need to switch it on for a single view in the app — is it possible? I have tried to get the reference to component and try to play with that, unfortunately without any luck.

Comment: The [SAP Design Guidelines on Letterboxing](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/v1-56/letter-boxing/) says you can achieve exactly this (look at the bottom of the page). However, although it mentions "_In some cases, applications may need to have the flexibility to change the width at runtime for different views. Example: fullWidth in view A and letterboxing in view B.
Through a new API, apps can change the width in the AppConfiguration service at runtime for different views_", it doesn't point to which API it actually is. Also, on StackOverflow, always post your code as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your App contains a Shell, then you don't set "fullWidth" in manifest.json, but yuo modify the Shells "appWidthLimited" property.

I made a [small example](http://embed.plnkr.co/E5jrJTQ3p4bSpNQy82N5/)